# How to validate Purescript typeclass laws?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, purescript

I use typeclasses, from libraries and my own, extensively in my Purescript code. Each typeclass law seems to provide a nice test. Currently, I'm writing tests individually for each class and law. Is there a way to partially automate this? Maybe something like Haskell's [quickcheck-classes](https://github.com/andrewthad/quickcheck-classes), which I, admittedly, haven't tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tests for the common core classes here: https://github.com/garyb/purescript-quickcheck-laws

I need to break out the various laws so they can be used independently too ideally, but maybe this will suit your needs anyway!

Comment: That gets me a long way there and also provides a template for my own class tests. Thanks!